# How to display categories in an unordered list

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to display a list of entries in an unordered list from a database. The problem I have now is how to loop through the array of data coming from the database to display in groups of say tens.

So the first ten categories will display in the first .
And subsequent categories also displayed in their respective s.

Eg.

```
<ul>
<li>Category 1 Item 1</li>
<li>Category 1 Item 1</li>
... .........................  . .......
<li>Category 1 Item 10</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Category 2 Item 1</li>
<li>Category 2 Item 1</li>
... .........................  . .......
<li>Category 2 Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you already have some PHP code? If you have, show where you're stuck.

Comment: my php code currently behaves similarly to the code posted by @Doug T below

Comment: Do you mean to say the first ten "items" will display in the first list?

Comment: This is not making sense. You are showing no code to work with, but you're unhappy if people give you answers based on that. Show some code

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I have now is how to loop
>   through the array of data coming from
>   the database to display in groups of
>   say tens.

How are your categories organized in your row? I'm going to assume you have a single "category" column that you're trying to organize by. AND that you've sorted it in the query by using [ORDER BY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by).

Then assuming you have an array of these sorted rows, you can just track when the category changes

```
$currCat = "NotaNumber";
$output = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($queryRes))
{
    # when the category changes, add closing and opening ul's 
    # we'll trim the excess </ul> and <ul> off later
    # You can change this to also limit the number printed
    # by combining with the other answer
    if ($row['categoryColumn'] != $currCat)
    {
        $output .= "</ul>";
        $output .= "<ul>";
        $currCat = $row['categoryColumn']; 
    }
    $output .= "<li> Category No: " . $row['categoryColumn'] . 
               " Data:" . $row['catData'] . "</li>";
}
# Trim </ul> from front and <ul> from back by getting a substring
$output = substr($output, 5, strlen($output) - 9);
echo $output
```

**Original answer**

Printing categories organized as array of arrays:

```
function printCategories($catItems)
{
   echo "<ul>";
   $numPrinted = 0;
   foreach ($catItems as $catItem)
   {
       echo "<li> $catEntry </li>"
       $numPrinted++;
       if ($numPrinted > 10)
       {
           break;
       }
   }

   echo "</ul>";
}

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
   printCategories($category);
}
```

Comment: Did you even read my question? There is more to it than just the title

Answer (score 1):

```
echo("<ul>");
$count = 0;
while(...fetch next row...) {
    if($count % 10 == 0)
        echo("</ul><ul>");
    echo("<li>" . $catName . "</li>");
    $count++;
}

echo("</ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of PHP tags in there, but I'm assuming you'll use this in your view so you're going to have HTML to fill it out in any case.

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($categories as $catgory) : ?>
   <?php if ($i == 0) : ?>
      <ul>
   <?php endif; ?>

       <li>$catgory</li>

   <?php if ($i == 9) : $i = 0 ?>
      </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/)

```
$categories = array_chunk($categories, 10);
$tal = new PHPTAL;
$tal->categories = $categories;

$html = <<<HTML
   <ul tal:repeat="category categories">
      <li tal:repeat="item category">
         Category ${repeat/category/number}
         Item ${repeat/item/number}
      </li>
   </ul>
HTML;
$tal->setSource($html, __FILE__);
echo $tal->execute();
```